# Loss function for ordinal multi classification in pytorch

Tags: optimization, neural-network, pytorch, loss-function

I am a beginner with DNN and pytorch.
I am dealing with a multi-classification problem where my label are encoded into a one-hotted vector, say of dimension `D`.
To this end, I am using the CrossEntropyLoss. However now I want to modify or change such criterion in order to penalize value distant from the actual one, say classify 4 instead of 5 is better than 2 instead of 5.

Is there a function already built-in in Pytorch that implement this behavior? Otherwise how can I modify the CrossEntropyLoss to achieve it?

Comment: This sounds like regression problem..doesn't it?

Comment: Answered already:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375401/neural-network-ordinal-classification-for-age

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neural Network Ordinal Classification for Age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375401/neural-network-ordinal-classification-for-age)

Answer (score 1):

This could help you. It is a PyTorch implementation ordinal regression:
https://www.ethanrosenthal.com/2018/12/06/spacecutter-ordinal-regression/