# Convnet Ordinal Regression Loss Function

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I am currently attempting transfer learning with Densenet trained on Imagenet, to output an ordinal integer value {2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 6}. I encoded the target variables into binary vectors of length 4 (i.e. [1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0],etc.) using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375401/neural-network-ordinal-classification-for-age). Below is the architecture of my model:

```
base_model = DenseNet121(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", classes=5, input_shape=(224,224,3))
base_model.trainable = False
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dropout(0.8)(x)
preds = Dense(4, activation="sigmoid", 
axis=1),
             )(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=preds, name = "ordered_logit")

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Nadam(), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[soft_acc_multi_output])
```

Where *'soft_acc_multi_output'* is my custom metric, that outputs 1 if all entries matches the true values and 0 otherwise.

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
def soft_acc_multi_output(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.all(K.equal(K.cast(K.round(y_true),'int32'), K.cast(K.round(y_pred),'int32')),axis=1))
```

I am currently using '*binary_crossentropy*', but I realized that it doesn't tell the model that, if the true label is [1,1,0,0], then [0.9, 0.7, 0, 0.6] should be penalized more heavily than [0.9, 0.7, 0.6, 0], but currently the penalties for them are identical. How should I modify the loss function to make it able to recognize this difference?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score -1):

When we need to use a loss function (or metric) other than the ones available , we need to construct our own custom loss function and pass to model.compile.

A metric function is similar to a loss function, except that the results from evaluating a metric are not used when training the model. We may use any of the loss functions as a metric function.

So build a custom loss function that uses the calculation that you have built for metric evaluation to identify the additional penalty or loss to be optimized by the model.